# how to do iphone-style slide animations in android?

Tags: java, iphone, android, slide

i'm designing an android app atm and i wonder how it is possible to switch between views with a "sliding" animation as on the iphone.

what i mean is that i want to stay in an Activity and slide from left to right (or vice versa) and PART of the views slide in the respective direction, making room for another view. the rest of the ui stays where it is.

it is actually possible, since i've seen it in an actual working (not yet published) app. so - how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the answer given to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994106/android-can-i-use-different-class-for-different-child-of-viewflipper)